# Angular2 with Patternlab

Tags: angular, mustache, patternlab.io

Atomic Design with Pattern lab & Angular 2.

We are trying to use pattern lab (with Mustache or Twig) in our Angular 2 project.

Any one has any idea on this ?

Comment: Have you seen [this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39515130/2450941)?